# How do you configure the Struts 2 Upload Folder?

Tags: java, tomcat, upload, struts2

At the moment, after uploading a file, the tmp file that gets created gets stored in:

> \Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat
>   7.0.22\work\Catalina\localhost\Project\upload__78a0adab_1380z353bfa__7gfe_00000000.tmp

How do I store it in my own custom directory? I've tried:

```
<param name="saveDir">/tmp</param>
```

But it still goes to the one I mentioned above.

**EDIT 1 - struts.xml:**

```
<action name="file_save" method="fileSave" class="FileActionBean">
            <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
                <param name="maximumSize">2097152</param>
                <param name="saveDir">/tmp</param>
                <param name="allowedTypes">
                    image/bmp,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/jpg,image/png
                </param>
            </interceptor-ref>
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
            <result type="redirect">file</result>
        </action>
```

**EDIT 2:**

I am using struts 2 version 2.1.8.1

Comment: I read this resource and followed it exactly as it is, but it still isn't working: http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/docs/handling-file-uploads.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using Spring?
In that case you can configure your ActionBean with your desired upload-directory.
Just add to your action-bean:

```
private String uploadDir;
public void setUploadDir(String uploadDir){
    this.uploadDir = uploadDir;
}
```

And modify your spring config `applicationContext.xml` to set the uploadDir. You can to it by setting value direct, or more preferably, by configfile as shown below:

```
<bean id="fileAction" class="FileActionBean" scope="prototype">
    <property name="uploadDir" value="${uploaddir}" />
</bean>
```

Update:

It is pretty easy to control where you want the file to be saved.
If the first character of your path string is not /, it will be relative to your "current" directory. 
So you dont really need any "root" path if you want to save it in the webapp directory. Just plain simply: `File file = new File("results.txt");`

Or if you want to store it somewhere else than your current directory you can either navigate using `../../something` or by just typing out the whole structure to where you want like: `File file = new File("/home/something/something/myFile.txt");`

Or in an windows environment you could try `File file = new File("Z:\\results\\results.txt");`

But it is not really a good idea to put your uploaded files in the same directory as the webapp. Then you will lose all your files every time you redeploy.

Comment: Will the .tmp files go here too after doing this?

Comment: In my example, i assume that you have in your action a setter for the File. E.g. setUploadFile(File file). This setter must match the name in the form. And then, as long as you allow .tmp files to be uploaded. The file will be set by the setter. Then it is up to you to store the file to disk in your action, using the upload-dir and the file.

Comment: Awesome. Could you possibly add an edit on how you get the webapp's root web directory. So I can simply say `String uploadDir = root + "/uploadDir";`. Which will essentially go somewhere like: `C:/project/build/web/uploadDir/`